# Programmatically test whether an arbitrary user has access to an arbitrary file

Tags: ruby, bash, rspec

I'd like to be able to write tests or specs that state that user `soandso` can read or edit file `such_and_such`.  Although I would ultimately like this to be in RSpec, I'm assuming it will either all boil down to Bash commands (neatly wrapped in Ruby methods, of course), since it doesn't seem to be available in Ruby's File class, or anything else I've looked at. I've been hunting around for something in Bash to do this, and can't find anything (and nothing in the File class looks useful either).  (Note: File.owned? does *not* do what I want, as it only tests if the process running the Ruby code is the owner, not if any arbitrary user has rights to edit or read, so it's significantly different on two counts.)

Is there any way to do this, built into Bash?  (Or Ruby, or some Ruby gem, that I missed?) Or do I need to build a system myself, by getting owner and group info for the file, as well as read, write, and execute bits for each, and then looking up members of the group (in case `so_and_so` is not the owner), and seeing if the desired permissions are available to `soandso` either through ownership or group membership?

I'm currently only concerned about doing this on Unix-like systems, although something not dependent on a Unix shell that would also run on Windows would be a nice bonus.

Also, I'm interested in testing *actual* files, so something like FakeFS is not (as far as I can see) useful to me.  I'm not trying to test how my Ruby code will interact with a file system, I'm trying to verify that all the necessary operations can be performed on actual files and directories.  (Again,) I want to be able to specify that `soandso` can edit (or read) file `such_and_such`, ***NOT*** specify that file `such_and_such` is owned by `soandso`.  The whole point of this is ***not*** specifying ownership (since that's an implementation detail and may need to change to accommodate other requirements, such as security) but only specify what my application and users *actually* need to be able to do to/in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

If the user running your Ruby script has the necessary permissions, you could try running a test with the specific user with `sudo`.

```
sudo -u soandso test -r such_and_such
```

`-r` tests readability, `-w` writability. The return code is `0` if the test is passed.

By the way, I think that since the feature you are looking for could only be available for the super-user (since figuring out whether someone else has enough permissions would need you to have read permissions at least), it makes sense that it is not readily available in Ruby File class.

Comment: Very interesting idea!  I hadn't thought of that.  Unfortunately it doesn't work in my case, but I like it nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I wonder if the FileTest methods would work as they say they operate on the "effective user id".

```
File.readable?(file_name) → true or false Link
Returns true if the named file is readable by the effective user id of this process.
File.writable?(file_name) → true or false Link
Returns true if the named file is writable by the effective user id of this process.
```

That in conjunction with seteuid might do the trick.

```
Process::Sys.seteuid(integer) → nil Link
Set the effective user ID of the calling process to integer. Not available on all platforms.
```

There is also `setegid` for group stuff...

Answer (score 0):

#### Parse Permissions with File::Stat and Etc Modules

While this isn't a pre-packaged solution, you should be able to inspect a given file where you have sufficient access for *stat* in order to get mode, uid, and gid information. You can then parse */etc/passwd* and */etc/group* in order to find out whether a given user would have sufficient permissions.

Some building blocks include:

```
# Get the file's octal mode.
File.stat('/etc/passwd').mode.to_s(8)
#=> "100644"

# Get the group ID assigned to the file.
File.stat('/etc/passwd').gid
#=> 0

# Get the username associated with the given GID.
Etc.getpwuid(0).name
#=> "root"
```

You could also use the *id* utility to get information about a given user. For example:

```
%x{id root}
#=> "uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)\n"
```

but I think it would be easier to use the standard libraries rather than parse the output from *id*. YMMV.

Comment: I agree that it's *better* to use the standard libraries, but parsing the output of shell commands seems easy enough.  Thinking in octal, on the other hand, makes my head hurt. ;)