# How to use bitwise operators in if statements?

Tags: bash, shell, bit-manipulation

I want to write something like this:

```
if [[ ( releases["token"] & $MASK ) -eq 1 ]]; then
```

but I get the error that:

> unexpected token `&', conditional binary operator expected

How do I use bitwise operators in if statements?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`Arithmetic Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion):

```
(((5&3)==1)) && echo YES || echo NO
```

It will print **YES**

Comment: If you want to use base 2 (binary) for your mask: `(( ( 5 & 2#00011 ) == 1 )) && echo YES || echo NO`

Answer (score 30):

## Logic vs Syntax

### .... or: "What's more to say?"

At first sight, as pointed out in @chepner's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318451/how-to-use-bitwise-operators-in-if-statements/23917229#comment59522097_35932323), the question might only be one of syntax, which causes the compilation error (`unexpected token '&', conditional binary operator expected`). And in fact, [@kev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14318764/3102305) addresses that by using [arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion), which is applied to the `If` statement in  [@Gustavo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23917229/3102305).

However, the question **"*how to use bitwise operators* in if statements"** is formulated in a more general manner and begs for an answer on how to ***use*** bitwise operators to check against `$MASK` (It was not the question of "how to avoid a syntax error when using binary comparison").

In fact, it may be assumed that the example code

> ```
> if [[ ( releases["token"] & $MASK ) -eq 1 ]]; then
> ```

was a work in progress of finding a solution and is explicitly marked as "something like ...". Now @kev's arbitrary assumption of

```
 releases["token"]=3
 MASK=5
```

might hide the fact, that there is also a logical misunderstanding in using `-eq 1` in the first place. So while @kev's answer works with the chosen values, the result of the input of e.g. `4` line in

```
 (((5&4)==1)) && echo YES || echo NO
```

would print **NO**, even though one would expect YES in that case as well, as `4` and `5` both have the 3rd bit set.

**So *this* answer addresses this *logical* error in the questions example and attempts an general answer the the question's headline.**

## First things first!

### ... or: "The Background of Bitwise Representation"

> to understand bitwise comparison it is helpful to visualise numbers in their bit representation (listed top-down in the following example):
>
> ```
> |-----------------------------------------------------------|
> |         |     hexadecimal representation of the value     |
> | bit val |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F |
> |---------|---------------------- bit ----------------------|
> |         |  shows if the given value has the given bit set |
> |  0      |  -  x  -  x  -  x  -  x  -  x  -  x  -  x  -  x |
> |  1      |  -  -  x  x  -  -  x  x  -  -  x  x  -  -  x  x |
> |  2      |  -  -  -  -  x  x  x  x  -  -  -  -  x  x  x  x |
> |  3      |  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x |
> |---------|---------------------- val ----------------------|
> |     shows the value that the given bit adds to the number |
> |  0   1  |  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1 |
> |  1   2  |  0  0  2  2  0  0  2  2  0  0  2  2  0  0  2  2 |
> |  2   4  |  0  0  0  0  4  4  4  4  0  0  0  0  4  4  4  4 |
> |  3   8  |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8 |
> |---------|-------------------------------------------------|
> |sum:  15 |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 |
> |         |       decimal representation of the value       |
> |===========================================================|
> ```

which is created by the following snippet:

```
( # start a subshell to encapsulate vars for easy copy-paste into the terminal
  # do not use this in a script!
echo ;
echo "|-----------------------------------------------------------|";
echo "|         |     hexadecimal representation of the value     |";
echo "| bit val |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F |";
echo "|---------|---------------------- bit ----------------------|";
echo "|         |  shows if the given value has the given bit set |";
mask=0;
for (( bit=0; bit<4; bit++)); do
    mask=$((1<<bit));
    echo -n "|  $bit      |"
    for ((x=0;x<16;x++)); do ((((x&mask)>0))&&echo -n '  x'||echo -n '  -'); done
    echo " |";
done ;
echo "|---------|---------------------- val ----------------------|";
echo "|     shows the value that the given bit adds to the number |";
mask=0;
for (( bit=0; bit<4; bit++)); do
    mask=$((1<<bit));
    echo -n "|  $bit   $mask  |"
    for ((x=0;x<16;x++)); do echo -n "  $((x&mask))"; done
    echo " |";
done ;
echo "|---------|-------------------------------------------------|";
echo "|sum:  15 |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 |";
echo "|         |       decimal representation of the value       |";
echo "|===========================================================|";
echo ;
)
```

## The curious case of `3 & 5` vs `4 & 5`

### ... or: "`==1` vs `>0` and the Differences of `&`, `|`, and `^`"

> if we now check the special case of the examples mentioned, we'll see the shortcoming:
>
> ```
> |------------------ value: 3 / mask: 5 -------------------|
> |         | value | mask  |  and  |  or   |  xor  | xnor  |
> |         |   3   |   5   | 3 & 5 | 3 | 5 | 3 ^ 5 |       |
> | bit val |bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|
> |---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
> |  0   1  | 1   1 | 1   1 | 1   1 | 1   1 | 0   0 | 0   0 |
> |  1   2  | 2   1 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 1   2 | 1   2 | 1   2 |
> |  2   4  | 0   0 | 4   1 | 0   0 | 1   4 | 1   4 | 1   4 |
> |  3   8  | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 |
> |---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
> |sum:     |     3 |     5 | ==> 1 |     7 |     6 |     6 |
> |---------|-----------------------------------------------|
> |check:   |  3 & 5 == 1 ? YES     |                       |
> |         |  3 & 5 >= 1 ? YES     | ==>  3 & 5 > 0 ? YES  |
> |=========================================================|
>
> |------------------ value: 4 / mask: 5 -------------------|
> |         | value | mask  |  and  |  or   |  xor  | xnor  |
> |         |   4   |   5   | 4 & 5 | 4 | 5 | 4 ^ 5 |       |
> | bit val |bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|
> |---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
> |  0   1  | 0   0 | 1   1 | 0   0 | 1   1 | 1   1 | 1   1 |
> |  1   2  | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 |
> |  2   4  | 4   1 | 4   1 | 1   4 | 1   4 | 0   0 | 0   0 |
> |  3   8  | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 | 0   0 |
> |---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
> |sum:     |     4 |     5 | ==> 4 |     5 |     1 |     1 |
> |---------|-----------------------------------------------|
> |check:   |  4 & 5 == 1 ? NO      |                       |
> |         |  4 & 5 >= 1 ? YES     | ==>  4 & 5 > 0 ? YES  |
> |=========================================================|
> ```

**Please pay particular attention to the following checks:**

> > ```
> > |---------|-----------------------------------------------|
> > |check:   |  3 & 5 == 1 ? YES     |                       |
> > |         |  3 & 5 >= 1 ? YES     | ==>  3 & 5 > 0 ? YES  |
> > ---------|------------------------------------------------|
> > |check:   |  4 & 5 == 1 ? NO      |                       |
> > |         |  4 & 5 >= 1 ? YES     | ==>  4 & 5 > 0 ? YES  |
> > |---------|-----------------------------------------------|
> > ```

The output above is created by the following snippet:

```
( # start a sub-shell to encapsulate vars for easy copy-paste into the terminal
  # do not use this in a script!
echo ;
for o in 3 4; do
echo "|------------------ value: $o / mask: 5 -------------------|";
echo "|         | value | mask  |  and  |  or   |  xor  | xnor  |";
echo "|         |   $o   |   5   | $o & 5 | $o | 5 | $o ^ 5 |       |";
echo "| bit val |bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|bit:val|";
echo "|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|";
mask=0;
for (( bit=0; bit<4; bit++)); do
    mask=$((1<<bit));
    echo -n "|  $bit   $mask "
    echo -n " | $(($o&mask))   $((($o&mask)>0))"
    echo -n " | $((5&mask))   $(((5&mask)>0))"
    echo -n " | $(((($o&mask)&(5&mask))>0))   $((($o&mask)&(5&mask)))"
    echo -n " | $(((($o&mask)|(5&mask))>0))   $((($o&mask)|(5&mask)))"
    echo -n " | $(((($o&mask)^(5&mask))>0))   $((($o&mask)^(5&mask)))"
    echo -n " | $(((($o&mask)^(5&mask))>0))   $((($o&mask)^(5&mask)))"
    echo " |";
done ;
echo "|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|";
echo -n "|sum:     |     $o |     5 |";
echo " ==> $(($o&5)) |     $(($o|5)) |     $(($o^5)) |     $(($o^5)) |";
echo "|---------|-----------------------------------------------|";
echo -n "|check:   |  $o & 5 == 1 ? $(((($o&5)==1))&&echo YES||echo "NO ")     ";
echo "|                       |";
echo -n "|         |  $o & 5 >= 1 ? $(((($o&5)>=1))&&echo YES||echo "NO ")     ";
echo "| ==>  $o & 5 > 0 ? $(((($o&5)>0))&&echo YES||echo "NO ")  |";
echo "|=========================================================|";
echo ;
done
echo ;
)
```

## Hello World!

### ... or: "Rise and Shine!"

> So how do we do it now?! Let's imagine, we have the following option set:
>
> ```
> # option set:
> option_1=1
> option_2=2
> option_3=4
> option_4=8
> option_5=16
> option_6=32
> option_7=64
> option_8=128
> option_9=256
> ```
>
> We could for example set a selection of those options in a
>   function and return the combined code as a return value. Or the other
>   way round: pass a selection of options as one numeric parameter.
>   Whatever your use case is, the options would be summed together:
>
> ```
> # set options:
> option = option_1
>        + option_4
>        + option_5
>        + option_9
> ```
>
> How do we best check, which options are set (`1`,`4`,`5`, & `9`)? It depends of course again on your use case, but i kinda like the `case` construct! Something like ...
>
> ```
> case $option in
>   0) echo "no option set!";;
>   1) echo "option 1";;
>   2) echo "option 2";;
>   3) echo "option 1 and 2";;
>   *) echo "...";;
> esac
> ```
>
> could work, but is not very nice, as we would have to construct every combination!

## And the winner is ...

### ... or: "The Real `Case`"

> We can use `case` in the following way instead ...
>
> ```
> echo "check for options using >0:"
> case 1 in
>   $(( (option & option_1) >0 )) ) echo "- option_1 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_2) >0 )) ) echo "- option_2 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_3) >0 )) ) echo "- option_3 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_4) >0 )) ) echo "- option_4 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_5) >0 )) ) echo "- option_5 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_6) >0 )) ) echo "- option_6 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_7) >0 )) ) echo "- option_7 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_8) >0 )) ) echo "- option_8 is set";;&
>   $(( (option & option_9) >0 )) ) echo "- option_9 is set";;&
> esac
> ```
>
> **Please note** that
>
> - the spaces within `$(( (option & option_1) >0 )) )` are completely optional and are added for readability. The last closing bracket `)` is for the `case` construct.
> - the *command-list*s are terminated with
>     [`;;&`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs),
>     in order to continue evaluation with the next option test. In case 
>     you want to abord further processing of the list, set `option=0` or 
>     to your current `option=option_X`.
>
> ... we get the following result:
>
> > ```
> > check for options using >0:
> > - option_1 is set
> > - option_4 is set
> > - option_5 is set
> > - option_9 is set
> > ```
>
> #### Hurray! :-)

### And `if` I was a rich man!

> ```
> echo "# to use it in an if statement:";
> if (((option&option_5)>0)); then
>   echo "- option_5 is set"    
> else
>   echo "- option_5 is NOT set"
> fi
>
> # to use it in an if statement:
> - option_5 is set
> ```

### But finally the poor man's condition:

> ```
> echo "# or to use it just for conditional execution:";
> (((option&option_6)>0)) \
> && echo "- option_6 is set" \
> || echo "- option_6 is NOT set"
>
> # or to use it just for conditional execution:
> - option_6 is NOT set
> ```

## "He who does not answer the questions has passed the test."

### ... or: 'Stay,' he said, 'that was only a test.'

(Kafka, 1975: 181)

> So it would be perfectly possible to use the solution as posted in the question, by the slight change as follows:
>
> ```
> (
> declare -A releases=([token]=4)
> declare -i MASK=5
>
> if [[ $(( releases["token"] & $MASK )) -gt 0 ]]; then
>   echo YES
> else
>   echo NO
> fi
> )
> ```
>
> The changes are the following:
>   - use `$(())` instead of `()` to do the test, which will return the value of the bitwise comparison
>   - use `-gt 0` instead of `-eq 1`

altogether in action:

```
( # start a sub-shell to encapsulate vars for easy copy-paste into the terminal
  # do not use this in a script!
echo ;

for ((i=0; i<9;i++)); do
    o="option_$((i+1))"
    declare -i $o=$((1<<$i))
    echo "$o = ${!o}"
done

echo ;
echo ;

echo "# set options:"
echo "option = option_1"
echo "       + option_4"
echo "       + option_5"
echo "       + option_9"

option=option_1+option_4+option_5+option_9

echo ;
echo ;

echo "check for options using >0:"
case 1 in
  $(( (option & option_1) >0 )) ) echo "- option_1 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_2) >0 )) ) echo "- option_2 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_3) >0 )) ) echo "- option_3 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_4) >0 )) ) echo "- option_4 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_5) >0 )) ) echo "- option_5 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_6) >0 )) ) echo "- option_6 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_7) >0 )) ) echo "- option_7 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_8) >0 )) ) echo "- option_8 is set";;&
  $(( (option & option_9) >0 )) ) echo "- option_9 is set";;&
esac

echo ;
echo ;

echo "# to use it in an if statement:";
echo "  => if (((option&option_5)>0));";
if (((option&option_5)>0)); then
    echo "- option_5 is set"    
else
    echo "- option_5 is NOT set"
fi

echo ;
echo ;

declare -A releases=([token]=4)
declare -i MASK=5

echo "# Does 4 pass the mask 5 in the test construct?";
echo "  => if [[ $(( releases["token"] & $MASK )) -gt 0 ]];";
if [[ $(( releases["token"] & $MASK )) -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo YES
else
    echo NO
fi

echo ;
echo ;

echo "# or to use it just for conditional execution:";
echo "  => (((option&option_6)>0)) && do || dont";
(((option&option_6)>0)) \
&& echo "- option_6 is set" \
|| echo "- option_6 is NOT set"

)
```

## The End

```
Exit 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is supposed to provide. The question is simply one of syntax.

Comment: @chepner, this answer shall explain "[h]ow to use bitwise operators in if statements". While yes, the simple answer is also one of syntax. However, I found that answer when I was looking for how to [check number bitwise in bash](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=bash+check+number+bitwise), and this was the second hit at the time of writing. I think my answer is a more comprehensive contribution and might help others to get to the solution quicker than I did, as when using `==1` it only works in certain conditions. It is possible that the question's author wasn't aware of that fact either.

Comment: @chepner, so i guess you down-voted my answer. Please reconsider. I argue my answer is a valuable contribution and well worked out. It adds value to the question and to the site as it gives a throughout answer to the topic of bitwise comparison with both theoretical information as well as practical examples.Thanks.

Comment: @chepner, well, that is your opinion and I respect that. However I think the information provided is still useful and valid for those who have difficulties (as I did before my investigation). For those who are only looking for syntax error, the answer is right there at the beginning, for those who want to know more, they can read further. So I kindly ask you again to remove your down-vote. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Martin, simply saying "use arithmetic expansion" doesn't answer the question "How to use bitwise operators in if statements?".

Comment: answers the question 'in droves'

Comment: TLDR; It's like ordering small fries and getting truck load of potatoes dumped on you.

Comment: Very long answer, I was only looking for how to use _Bitwise &_, but I think it's good that you point out that `-eq 1` is only valid for some situations, and I learned that you can continue a case evaluation, thanks. So you got a vote. But you are aware of that if you end a sourced script with `exit 0` you will be logged out, and it's not `Exit 0` BTW :)

Answer (score 4):

In if statement:

```
if (((releases["token"] & $MASK) == 1)); then 
  echo YES
else 
  echo NO
fi
```